# Limit access to public ip (whitelist)

Tags: azure, vpn, whitelist

I want to set up a kubernetes cluster with a loadbalancer. Kubernetes will create a load balancer in azure and connect a public ip address with it.

But I don't want to make the api public, it should be exclusive for my api management service.

I tried to direct the load balancer into a vnet with the api service but I found nothing.

So I thought I could just limit the access to the public ip (a whitelist with only the incluced ip of my service) but I found nothing on the internet.

Is it possible to set such rule on a public ip or do I need some extra service for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With Kubernetes, assuming you have a service defined

Use the following commands:

```
kubectl get service
kubectl edit svc/<YOUR SERVICE>
```

change the type from LoadBalancer to ClusterIP

Now you can consume internally the service.